# Recorrer elementos por nombre, android

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de encuesta el cual implemento muchos `RadioButton`. Dentro de este proyecto estoy implementando una funcionalidad que recupera el estado de la interfaz mediante base de datos SQLite, por lo cual necesito seleccionar los `RadioButton` respecto a lo que se grabó. Con esto quiero decir:

Si tengo 100 Radiobutton estos tienen un nombre así:

```
(Radio_1, Radio_2, Radio_3, Radio_4, Radio_5.......Radio_100);
```

Si quiero cambiar el estado de cada uno, lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```
findViewById(R.id.Radio_1).setChecked(true);
findViewById(R.id.Radio_2).setChecked(true);
findViewById(R.id.Radio_3).setChecked(true);
.
.
.
.
findViewById(R.id.Radio_100).setChecked(true);
```

Pero, hay alguna forma de poner esto en un ciclo For? Así el código seria mucho mas eficaz

Comment: Nunca he trabajado en android, pero hay cosas muy similares a java. Haz intentado hacer un for (i = 0; i < 101; i++){ findViewById(R.id.Radio_[i]).setChecked(true); } o for (i = 0; i < 101; i++){ findViewById(R.id.Radio_"[i]").setChecked(true); }

Comment: No se puede de esa forma el compilador arroja error

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente crea un arreglo conteniendo los recursos, obviamente sería un array de valores enteros:

```
 int[] elementos = {R.id.Radio_1, R.id.Radio_2, R.id.Radio_3};
```

**Es necesario agregues los id existentes dentro del proyecto ya que estan relacionados a un valor dentro del archivo `R.java`.**

Recorrerías de esta forma para asignar el nuevo estado a todos los elementos :

```
  for(int i = 0; i < elementos.length ; i++){
        ((RadioButton)findViewById(elementos[i])).setChecked(true);
    }
```